# Unset all paths before node boot

Tags: erlang

**TLDR**;
When starting erlang node (using just `erl` command for an instance), how could I force it not to use local OTP libraries and get `code:get_path()` empty?

*Rationale.*

I want to touch `erl_boot_server`. Don't doing something certain, just playing. I have built sample release and want to load it via network. Here is it.

```
[vkovalev@t30nix foobar]$ tree -L 2
.
|-- bin
|   |-- foobar
|   |-- foobar-0.0.0+build.1.ref307ae38
|   |-- install_upgrade.escript
|   |-- nodetool
|   `-- start_clean.boot
|-- erts-6.1
|   |-- bin
|   |-- doc
|   |-- include
|   |-- lib
|   |-- man
|   `-- src
|-- lib
|   |-- foobar-0.1.0
|   |-- kernel-3.0.1
|   |-- sasl-2.4
|   `-- stdlib-2.1
`-- releases
    |-- 0.0.0+build.1.ref307ae38
    |-- RELEASES
    `-- start_erl.data
```

First I start boot node.

```
[vkovalev@t30nix foobar]$ erl -sname boot -pa lib/*/ebin -pa releases/0.0.0+build.1.ref307ae38/ -s erl_boot_server start localhost

(boot@t30nix)1> {ok, _, _} = erl_prim_loader:get_file("foobar.boot").
(boot@t30nix)2> {ok, _, _} = erl_prim_loader:get_file("foobar_app.beam").
```

As you can see, all okay here. Then I start slave node:

```
[vkovalev@t30nix ~]$ erl -sname slave -loader inet -hosts 127.0.0.1  -boot foobar
{"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot get bootfile','foobar.boot'}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

I dug into erl_prim_loader and found [that stuff](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/preloaded/src/erl_prim_loader.erl#L673). One clause acts when Paths is empty (it just forward requested filename to boot server as is), another acts when Paths is non-empty. In this case (I wonder why) prim loader cripples requested file name with its own (clientside) paths and then ask SERVER to serve this path. In my understanding this is quite weird thing, but okay. Then I checked `code:get_path()` on slave node, and yes, it has paths to local otp installation.

So, returning to subject. How could I force slave node not to use any local OTP installation (if it already presents)?

UPD: Added more investigation results.

1. First thing -
   https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/preloaded/src/erl_prim_loader.erl#L669.
   erl_prim_loader (in inet mode) for some (unclear for me) reasons tries
   to cripple any requested module with local (clientside) paths.
2. It seems there is no way to force loader on slave node to keep its
   paths empty: https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/preloaded/src/init.erl#L697
3. Paths in my bootscript looks like
   {path,["$ROOT/lib/kernel-4.0/ebin","$ROOT/lib/stdlib-2.5/ebin"]}, so
   it seems, if I'll get bootscript loaded, anyway, I won't be able boot
   system with it.

What's going on? Is erlang network boot feature broken? Or just my
brains? How could I get node successfully network-booted?

Answer (score 0):

Do you think node of slave type is just named by "slave"?

The following code from the project tsung, file named "ts_os_mon_erlang.erl".

```
start_beam(Host) ->
    Args = ts_utils:erl_system_args(),
    ?LOGF("Starting os_mon beam on host ~p ~n", [Host], ?NOTICE),
    ?LOGF("~p Args: ~p~n", [Host, Args], ?DEB),
    slave:start(list_to_atom(Host), ?NODE, Args).
```

In additon, the slave module restriction as follows:

```
Slave nodes on other hosts than the current one are started with the program rsh. The user must be allowed to rsh to the remote hosts without being prompted for a password. This can be arranged in a number of ways (refer to the rsh documentation for details). A slave node started on the same host as the master inherits certain environment values from the master, such as the current directory and the environment variables. For what can be assumed about the environment when a slave is started on another host, read the documentation for the rsh program.

An alternative to the rsh program can be specified on the command line to erl as follows: -rsh Program.

The slave node should use the same file system at the master. At least, Erlang/OTP should be installed in the same place on both computers and the same version of Erlang should be used.
```

If you want to start a node with different path, I think you could do it by script with differnt environment variable, for master node, not slave node.

Comment: The question was not about slaves which are started using `slave` module, but about those slaves that use `erl_boot_server` to load code. They are slaves too. See `http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_boot_server.html`. And I do not want to start node with "different paths", I want to completely unset all paths and keep ampty according variable in `erl_prim_loader`. To make things clearer, I've updated original questions with detailed investigation results.

Answer (score 0):

I think rebar project's can help for the similiar purpose. It include how to manipulate the path:

From `rebar_core.erl` file:
    process_dir1(Dir, Command, DirSet, Config, CurrentCodePath,
                 {DirModules, ModuleSetFile}) ->
        Config0 = rebar_config:set(Config, current_command, Command),
        %% Get the list of modules for "any dir". This is a catch-all list
        %% of modules that are processed in addition to modules associated
        %% with this directory type. These any_dir modules are processed
        %% FIRST.
        {ok, AnyDirModules} = application:get_env(rebar, any_dir_modules),

```
    Modules = AnyDirModules ++ DirModules,

    %% Invoke 'preprocess' on the modules -- this yields a list of other
    %% directories that should be processed _before_ the current one.
    {Config1, Predirs} = acc_modules(Modules, preprocess, Config0,
                                     ModuleSetFile),

    %% Remember associated pre-dirs (used for plugin lookup)
    PredirsAssoc = remember_cwd_predirs(Dir, Predirs),

    %% Get the list of plug-in modules from rebar.config. These
    %% modules may participate in preprocess and postprocess.
    {ok, PluginModules} = plugin_modules(Config1, PredirsAssoc),

    {Config2, PluginPredirs} = acc_modules(PluginModules, preprocess,
                                           Config1, ModuleSetFile),

    AllPredirs = Predirs ++ PluginPredirs,

    ?DEBUG("Predirs: ~p\n", [AllPredirs]),
    {Config3, DirSet2} = process_each(AllPredirs, Command, Config2,
                                      ModuleSetFile, DirSet),

    %% Make sure the CWD is reset properly; processing the dirs may have
    %% caused it to change
    ok = file:set_cwd(Dir),

    %% Check that this directory is not on the skip list
    Config7 = case rebar_config:is_skip_dir(Config3, Dir) of
                  true ->
                      %% Do not execute the command on the directory, as some
                      %% module has requested a skip on it.
                      ?INFO("Skipping ~s in ~s\n", [Command, Dir]),
                      Config3;

                  false ->
                      %% Check for and get command specific environments
                      {Config4, Env} = setup_envs(Config3, Modules),

                      %% Execute any before_command plugins on this directory
                      Config5 = execute_pre(Command, PluginModules,
                                            Config4, ModuleSetFile, Env),

                      %% Execute the current command on this directory
                      Config6 = execute(Command, Modules ++ PluginModules,
                                        Config5, ModuleSetFile, Env),

                      %% Execute any after_command plugins on this directory
                      execute_post(Command, PluginModules,
                                   Config6, ModuleSetFile, Env)
              end,

    %% Mark the current directory as processed
    DirSet3 = sets:add_element(Dir, DirSet2),

    %% Invoke 'postprocess' on the modules. This yields a list of other
    %% directories that should be processed _after_ the current one.
    {Config8, Postdirs} = acc_modules(Modules ++ PluginModules, postprocess,
                                      Config7, ModuleSetFile),
    ?DEBUG("Postdirs: ~p\n", [Postdirs]),
    Res = process_each(Postdirs, Command, Config8,
                       ModuleSetFile, DirSet3),

    %% Make sure the CWD is reset properly; processing the dirs may have
    %% caused it to change
    ok = file:set_cwd(Dir),

    %% Once we're all done processing, reset the code path to whatever
    %% the parent initialized it to
    restore_code_path(CurrentCodePath),

    %% Return the updated {config, dirset} as result
    Res.

restore_code_path(no_change) ->
    ok;
restore_code_path({added, Paths}) ->
    %% Verify that all of the paths still exist -- some dynamically
    %% added paths can get blown away during clean.
    [code:del_path(F) || F <- Paths, erl_prim_loader_is_file(F)],
    ok.

erl_prim_loader_is_file(File) ->
    erl_prim_loader:read_file_info(File) =/= error.
```

Comment: Sorry, but how this stuff can help? `erl_prim_loader` is process that started right after init. This is too early startup stage. At this moment  very restricted modules set available on node. There are only modules that prebuilt into emulator: https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/maint/erts/preloaded/src

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the `-setcookie` option. From the `erl -man erl` page:

> -loader Loader:
>
> Specifies   the   method   used  by  erl_prim_loader  to
>              load  Erlang  modules  in to  the  system.  See
>              erl_prim_loader(3). Two Loader methods are supported, 
>              efile and inet. efile means  use  the  local  file
>              system,  this  is  the default. inet means use a boot
>              server on another machine, and the -id, -hosts and
>              -setcookie flags must be specified as well. If Loader
>              is something else, the user supplied  Loader  port
>              program is started.